# EJB application won't deploy in OC4J with Java7

Tags: java-7, oc4j

An EJB application which works using Java6 JRE fails to deploy with Java7, it throws the following error:

> 14/01/13 13:33:23 WARNING: Application.setConfig Application:
>   accesscontrolapp is in failed state as initialization failed. 
>   oracle.classloader.util.AnnotatedNoClassDefFoundError:
>
> ```
> Missing class: org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode
> ```
>
> Dependent class: com.sun.enterprise.deployment.xml.EjbBundleNode
>              Loader: oc4j:10.1.3
>         Code-Source: .../oc4j_standalone/j2ee/home/lib/oc4j-internal.jar
>   Configuration:  in META-INF/boot.xml in
>   ...\oc4j_standalone\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar
>
> The missing class is not available from any code-source or loader in
>   the system.

I located the missing class in j2ee/home/lib/crimson_1_1_3.jar so I don't understand, why the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to META-INF/boot.xml within oc4j.jar, if you look at that file it reads:

> ```
>     <code-source path="lib/crimson_1_1_3.jar" if="java.specification.version == /1\.[5-6]/"/>
> ```

This was apparently done to prevent loading of crimson in java 1.4.  If you change this to read '[5-9]' then this works for Java 1.7 and presumably 1.8 and 1.9 as well.